# How to save multiple images to firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

Currently I have an app where hen the user takes a picture it automatically gets saved in storage and then I save an url to the image in storage. But whenever I add new images it just changes the old one to the new one. I want to append new ones. The end goal is for a user to be able to save an array of images he took to firebase under his account.

Bellow is my code for saving the images a user takes:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

//            let imageToUse = PhotoArray()

//            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPickedImage) //here convert to data

            PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray.append(userPickedImage)  //append converted data in array

            //                do {
            //                    try realm.write {
            //                        realm.add(imageToUse)
            //                    }
            //                } catch {
            //                    print(“error adding image to array\(error)“)
            //                }

            imageView.image = userPickedImage
//-----------------------------//
            //Create a reference to the image
            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("image.jpg")

            // Get image data
            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPickedImage) {

                // Upload image to Firebase Cloud Storage
                imageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        // Handle error
                        return
                    }
                    // Get full image url
                    imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        guard let downloadURL = url else {
                            // Handle error
                            return
                        }

                        // Save url to database
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("images").document("myImage").setData(["imageUrl" : downloadURL.absoluteString])
                    }
                }
            }
//-----------------------------//
        }
//        print(PhotoArray().photosArray.count)
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet of how I got multiple images to save with Firebase storage. I called uploadProfileImage() twice and set the NSUUID().uuidString inside the Storage path so basically on each instance the function is called, the time of the call would be a barely different and not overwrite :)

```
@IBAction func saveImages(_ sender: Any) {

    self.uploadProfileImage(frontImage!) { url in

        if url != nil {
            print("success")

        } else {
            print("failed!")
        }

    }
    self.uploadProfileImage(backImage!) { url in

        if url != nil {
            print("success")

        } else {
            print("failed!")
        }

    }


    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let imageTime = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("users/\(uid)/\(imageTime)")

    let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
        if error == nil, metaData != nil {

            storageRef.downloadURL{ url, error in
                completion(url)
            }

        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save images to Firebase Cloud Firestore. You could try using Firebase Cloud Storage, by going to Google and searching for the Firebase Cloud Storage docs.

Comment: I think I was already able to. But as my question states its not working as intended. Are you saying this isnot a good Idea? What shoould I do instead and how?

Comment: Well, I don't know off of the top of my head, but I'm guessing you would be able to use Cloud Storage. If you just search on Google for the Firebase Cloud Storage docs, they can tell you how to use it.